# Relation between closed subschemes and saturated ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $X=\operatorname{Proj}A$.

For any homogeneous ideal $I\subset A$, define the *saturation*
$I^{\rm sat}:=\{f\in A\mid (x_0,\dots,x_n)^mf\subset I$ for some $m\ge0\}$.

$I$ is called a *saturated* ideal if $I=I^{\rm sat}$.

I know that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the saturated ideals of $A$ and closed subschemes of $X$. In particular, $\operatorname{Proj}(A/I^{\rm sat})=\operatorname{Proj}(A/J^{\rm sat})$ if and only if $I^{\rm sat}=J^{\rm sat}$.

My question is that

> If $\operatorname{Proj}(A/I^{\rm sat})\subseteq \operatorname{Proj}(A/J^{\rm sat})$ (as closed subschemes) then $J^{\rm sat}\subseteq I^{\rm sat}$? Is $J^{\rm sat}\nsubseteq I^{\rm sat}$ possible?

Comment: Couldn't you just up the degrees? As long as the quotients agree in high enough degrees you have equality.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: if $I^{sat}=(q_1,q_2),J^{sat}=(q_3)$  ($q_1,q_2,q_3$ are quadics) in the above situation and $Proj(A/I^{sat})\subset Proj(A/J^{sat})$ then $q_3\in (q_1,q_2)?$